# Returning values in Vue template

Tags: vuejs2

I cannot get values in my template while i have the data, here is my code:

## code

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{project}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['id'],
        data() {
            return{
                project:[]
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchProject();
        },
        methods:{
            fetchProject(){
                var self = this;
                axios.post('/showprojectvue/' +self.id).then(res => {
                        self.project.push(res.data);
                    });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

`output`

```
[ { "id": 33, "user_id": 2, "title": "kjfsdjowhd", "slug": "kjfsdjowhd", "body": "<p>khweihgtfihrwhtg</p>", "attachment": null, "projectclass": "sthrh", "budget": 36346, "deadline": "2018-08-24", "published": "n", "runing": "n", "payment_verified": "n", "created_at": "2018-08-05 03:43:16", "updated_at": "2018-08-05 03:43:16" } ]
```

i cannot use any of `{{project.title}}` or `{{project['title']}}`

## How can I get out my data?

Comment: Do you have any output when you do console.log(res)

Comment: No i didn't make console.log i used vue console `chrome extension`

Comment: this would have worked in your case {{project[0].title}}

Answer (score 1):

As your data is an array you need to use `v-for` to iterate over it.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="obj in project">
        {{obj.title}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Example,

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {
        project : []
        },
        methods: { 
        ajaxCall(){
          this.project=[{ "id": 33, "user_id": 2, "title": "kjfsdjowhd", "slug": "kjfsdjowhd", "body": "<p>khweihgtfihrwhtg</p>", "attachment": null, "projectclass": "sthrh", "budget": 36346, "deadline": "2018-08-24", "published": "n", "runing": "n", "payment_verified": "n", "created_at": "2018-08-05 03:43:16", "updated_at": "2018-08-05 03:43:16" }];
          }
        },
        
    })
}
callMe()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
 <button type="button" @click="ajaxCall">Click ME</button>
  <div v-for="obj in project">
   Title:  {{obj.title}}
   <p>
   Object:{{obj}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I&#39;ve tried that bro not returning data, infact I don&#39;t want my data be array, this is single page data (imagine post view, where you read post description) what should I do?

Comment: Thanks man i think i should change `project:[]` to `project:''`

Comment: try writing {{project[0].title}} if its a single array

Comment: Change  `self.project.push(res.data)` to `self.project.push(res.data[0])` and `project:[]` to `project:null`

Comment: changing project from [] to null is not making any difference in when I tested. Doing `self.project.push(res.data[0])` is right.